# How to get Original Rows filtered by a HAVING Condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the method in T-SQL to select the orginal values limited by a HAVING attribute. For example, if I have

```
A|B
10|1
11|2
10|3
```

How would I get all the values of B (Not An Average or some other summary stat), Grouped by A, having a Count (Occurrences of A) greater than or equal two 2?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you have several options to choose from

**1. You could make a subquery out of your original having statement and join it back to your table**

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable yt
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT A
         FROM   YourTable
         GROUP BY
                A
         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
       ) cnt ON cnt.A = yt.A
```

**2. another equivalent solution would be to use a WITH clause**

```
  ;WITH cnt AS (
    SELECT A
    FROM   YourTable
    GROUP BY
           A
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
  )
      SELECT *
      FROM   YourTable yt
             INNER JOIN cnt ON cnt.A = yt.A
```

**3. or you could use an IN statement**

```
      SELECT *
      FROM   YourTable yt
      WHERE  A IN (SELECT A FROM YourTable GROUP BY A HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Seems like what I think I am going to want, although I left out that in my case A will be the result of a function (i.e. DATEDIFF). So not sure how to join on a function?

Comment: @KyleBrandt - If you provide some sample data and expected results, I'm sure it is possible to come up with something.

Answer (score 2):

A self join will work:

```
select B
from table
join(
  select A
  from table
  group by 1
  having count(1)>1
)s
using(A);
```

Comment: I've never seen this kind of syntax before (but that doesn't mean anything). Are you sure this is valid SQL? Do you have any references?

Comment: @Lieven - I don't have a version of MS-SQL hanging around, but this is valid syntax in PostgreSQL.  Regardless, it's a trivial matter of converting the syntax of such a simple query from one SQL dialect to another.

Comment: `USING` and `GROUP BY (ordinal)` is not supported in SQL Server. The latter is bad practice anyway

Comment: How is it bad practice in a query with only one column?  Fine, if you're using SQL Server, then replace `group by 1` with `group by A`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function (no joins, only one table scan):

```
select * from (
  select *, cnt=count(*) over(partiton by A) from table
) as a 
where cnt >= 2
```